# Windows 7 jump list doesn't do anything

Tags: windows-7, windows

I know there are similar questions out there regarding issues with jump lists not working properly, but I've been unable to find any with the same issue as me.

Take Chrome for example. I right click on it, select new window and nothing happens. Same goes for all other applications:

[image: Chrome Jump List]

Now, writing this made me realize that the term "Jump List" may in fact not be the right one to use. I do believe that a jump list is a list of the last used applications of the program. I'm not sure, though.

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: You write "Take Chrome for example. I right click on it, select new window and nothing happens. " <-- try left clicking on 'new window' !! Did you really not do that?! If you did and it didn't respond then try  restarting or getting a new mouse

Comment: And yes that new kind of menu you show from the taskbar is called a jump list. It comes from right clicking or from left clicking and dragging upwards.  The regular one comes from holding shift and right clicking the icon.

Comment: Before you start throwing all sorts of nasty comments at me try think about what I wrote. I meant opening the jump list BY right clicking and then left clicking on the appropriate option, in this case "New Window".

I've rebooted several times, thank you.
I do not see how getting a new mouse would solve anything as I am easily able to left click as I would otherwise have noticed it while making this post.

Comment: Nothing I wrote to you was nasty. And since you're saying it didn't work and all you said was you selected it, you -really- should have written in your question that you left clicked it. It's quite crucial. And since this kind of thing can often be Windows crashing issue, e.g. not enough RAM free, you should have written that you've tried restarting and still have the same problem. You should always state clearly what you did. It's very very relevant that this is an issue that persists even after a restart.

Comment: You say this happens for other apps. OK. Try safe mode.